# How can I turn the rowid column into a regular column?

Tags: sqlite, primary-key, alter-table, rowid

I create a table and insert a row :

```
CREATE TABLE people (first_name text NOT NULL, last_name text NOT NULL );
INSERT INTO people (first_name, last_name) VALUES ('John', 'Doe');
```

I execute:

```
SELECT rowid as ID, first_name, last_name FROM people
```

and get three fields as expected. However, I want to turn the automatic `rowid` column into a regular column so the IDs of the rows do not change as they are removed, etc. How can I do this?

I tried :

```
ALTER TABLE people ADD people_id INTEGER;
ALTER TABLE people ADD PRIMARY KEY (people_id);
```

The first statement succeeds, but the second one gives me an error:

> near "PRIMARY": syntax error: ALTER TABLE people ADD PRIMARY

If I had created the table as:

```
CREATE TABLE people (people_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, first_name text NOT NULL, last_name text NOT NULL );
```

I would have, from the start, had the kind of table I want.

It is important the `rowid` value is maintained in the `people_id` column. For example, John Doe has `rowid` 47 in `people`. After the transformation `people_id` for John Doe needs to be 47.

I can copy the data from one table to another, but wonder if there is a better way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shawn's answer is sound (and I've upvoted it), but I'll offer a variation on that which I think is slightly neater in that the new table does not end up in the schema with quotes:

```
TRANSACTION;
ALTER TABLE people RENAME TO old_people;
CREATE TABLE people(people_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
                  , first_name TEXT NOT NULL,
                  , last_name TEXT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO people(people_id, first_name, last_name)
            SELECT rowid, first_name, last_name FROM old_people;
DROP TABLE old_people;
COMMIT;
VACUUM;
```

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to create a new table, copy everything over, drop the old table, and rename the new one:

```
CREATE TABLE new_people(people_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
                      , first_name TEXT NOT NULL,
                      , last_name TEXT NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO new_people(first_name, last_name) SELECT first_name, last_name FROM people;
DROP TABLE people;
ALTER TABLE new_people RENAME TO people;
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as the actual storage format of the table does not change, you can use an *extremely dangerous* [backdoor](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_writable_schema) to change the table definition:

```
PRAGMA writable_schema = on;

UPDATE sqlite_master
SET sql = 'CREATE TABLE people(people_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, first_name text NOT NULL, last_name text NOT NULL )'
WHERE type = 'table'
  AND name = 'people';

-- and now re-open the database file
```

Answer (score -1):

This creates a new column and then set it equal to the rowid:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ADD COLUMN id INTEGER;
UPDATE mytable SET id=rowid;
```